# Apache Websocket Proxy dropped connections

Tags: apache, proxy, websocket, mod-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to proxy a websocket through Apache 2.4.7 (running on Ubuntu).
The connection is correctly established but if the browser or the server don't send each other data for some time (few minutes) new messages coming from the server are not delivered to the browser.
Furthermore, nor the browser or the service on the server seem to realize the connection is somehow broken (they don't throw any error at all).

How can I configure the server in order to avoid this issue?

This is my configuration:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /somepath ws://127.0.0.1:6080/ retry=60 keepalive=On timeout=9999 ttl=9999
ProxyPassReverse /somepath ws://127.0.0.1:6080/ retry=60
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and resolved it by configuring `ProxyWebsocketIdleTimeout`, with a value of 300 (seconds). There's documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

Your socket should have a keepalive message. Mine does every 30 seconds, but the connection was dropping because my ProxyWebsocketIdleTimeout directive was obviously less than 30 seconds. I set it to 300 seconds (5 minutes) for good measure and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it seems that for Apache to handle websockets you need to install the proxy websockets module using `a2enmod proxy_wstunnel`.

As pre-requisites, the proxy and proxy_http modules should also be installed using: `a2enmod proxy` and `a2enmod proxy_http`.